# Printing all binary strings of length N using recursion (in c)

Tags: c, recursion, binary

I need to print all binary string of length N counting from 0 to the highest number that can represented. My code below works for generating all of the strings. The problem I am having is that the strings are not in order from least to greatest.

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 10

char binarystrings[MAX_LENGTH];

void binary(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        printf("%s\n", binarystrings);
    } else {
        binarystrings[n-1] = '0';
        binary(n-1);
        binarystrings[n-1] = '1';
        binary(n-1);
    }
}

int main() {
    int length;
    scanf("%d", &length);
    binary(length);
}
```

When my program takes in 3 it generates:

```
000
100
010
110
001
101
011
111
```

But I need it to generate:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

How should I go about making my program put the numbers out in the right order?

Comment: Did you notice that the reverse of each line is in the order you want?

Comment: Yes, I did. I could've used used string reverse but it wouldn't have helped me to see why they were out of order. I now see that I was filling the array backwards so now I can avoid string reverse entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You  are filling the `binarystring` right to left. Fill it left to right instead. For that you need to pass two parameters (e.g. position and length) to `binary`:

```
void binary(int index, int length)
{
    if (index == length)
        return;
    binarystring[index] = 0;
    binary(index + 1, length);
    binarystring[index] = 1;
    binary(index + 1, length);
}
```

and call it as `binary(0, length)`.

Answer (score 0):

what about printf("%s\n", strrev(binarystrings)); It would probably be safer to reverse the string and check for error then print it and initializing your char array to contain nulls..and finally doesn't the array need to be MAX_LENGTH +1

Answer (score 0):

u can try my code ... i have got the answer in the right pattern:

```
enter code here

#include <stdio.h>
void printBinary(int a[],int n){
    
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
}

void generateBinaryString(int n,int a[],int i){
    
    if (i==n){
        printBinary(a,n);
        return;
    }
    
    a[i]=0;
    generateBinaryString(n,a,i+1);
    a[i]=1;
    generateBinaryString(n,a,i+1);
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("printing the binary string for n nos.");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    
    generateBinaryString(n,a,0);

    return 0;
}
```